# Trying to get a bit of jQuery to work on IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This code is meant to take every menu item in my .nav bar and space them evenly across the navholder.
It currently does precisely nothing in IE7.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $('.nav > li > a').length;
    var b = $('#navholder').width() - $('.nav').width();
    var c = (b/a)/2;
    $('.nav > li').css('margin','0 '+Math.floor(c-3)+'px');
});
```

does anyone know why?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Are there any errors in the IE developer tools console?

Comment: Put `console.log(a, b, c)` or `alert(a + "," + b + "," + c)` in there after you assign the variables, just to see what values you're getting.  Compare the values on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var b = $('#navholder').css('width') - $('.nav').css('width');
```

instead of:

```
 var b = $('#navholder').width() - $('.nav').width();
```